# How to show 2 different menu options in a single activity

Tags: android

I followed [this tutorial](http://android-er.blogspot.com/2009/12/implement-option-menu-using-xml.html) which shows menu option when value return True in this line: `myMenuInflater.inflate(R.menu.menu, menu);`

How do I add another menu option when value returns false? I want to show 2 different menu options in the same menu button. My code:

```
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.widget.Toast;
public class AndroidOptionMenu extends Activity {
  /** Called when the activity is first created. */ 
  @Override  public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
  {      
      super.onCreate(savedInstanceState); 
      setContentView(R.layout.main); 
  } 
  @Override public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu)
  {
      MenuInflater myMenuInflater = getMenuInflater();
      myMenuInflater.inflate(R.menu.menu, menu);     
      return true;
  }
  @Override public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) 
  {  
      switch(item.getItemId()) {   
      case(R.id.menu_OK):
          Toast.makeText(this, "OK", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show(); 
          break; 
      case(R.id.menu_help):
          Toast.makeText(this, "Help", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();  
          break; 
      case(R.id.menu_Cancel):  
          Toast.makeText(this, "Cancel", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
          break; 
      }   
      return true; 
  } 
}
```

Comment: I don't think you understand exactly what that code sample is showing you.  Why don't you try to change the return value of MenuInflater to false and see what happens?  Would you be surprised if you didn't see any menu at all?

Comment: i want to show two diffrent menu option when value is true and when value is false

Comment: Please read this options menu tutorial:

http://mobile.tutsplus.com/tutorials/android/android-sdk-implement-an-options-menu/

You will never, ever run into a situation where the MenuInflater returns false because it's hardcoded to return true.  Why should it always return true?  Because if it returns false, the menu won't open at all.

Your problem is that you don't have a good enough understanding of Android options menus.  Please take the time to study and understand any one of the many options menu tutorials available on the Internet.

Answer (score 2):

You can't.

At least not using the return value of onCreateOptionsMenu().

From [Android Doc for onCreateOptionsMenu()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#onCreateOptionsMenu%28android.view.Menu%29): 
`You must return true for the menu to be displayed; if you return false it will not be shown.`

You need to find another way to decide when to show your first and when to show the second menu, then you can do:

```
@Override public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu)
{
      MenuInflater myMenuInflater = getMenuInflater();
    if(showFirstMenu)
    {
        myMenuInflater.inflate(R.menu.menu, menu);     
    } else {
        myMenuInflater.inflate(R.menu.menu2, menu); // here you show the other menu
    }
      return true;
}
```

Comment: You can replace `showFirstMenu` with any condition you need to decide which menu should be shown.

Answer (score 2):

As I remember, you can set which menu item shown at menu at the run time with onPrepareOptionsMenu. with that you can group menu items as first menu's or second's and select which one to show. 
And you could try;

```
    @Override 
    public boolean onPrepareOptionsMenu(Menu menu)
    {

        MenuInflater myMenuInflater = getMenuInflater();
        if(condition)
        {
          myMenuInflater.inflate(R.menu.menu, menu);     
        } else {
          myMenuInflater.inflate(R.menu.menu2, menu); // here you show the other menu
        }
        return true;
    }
```

I hope that works.